# how to access printer bridged via dd-wrt

Tags: networking, printer, dd-wrt, wireless-bridge

I have a Brother Printer with a LAN port in the back.  I have a TP-LINK WR841N router that I just installed DD-WRT on in order to bridge the printer to my main Wireless network.  Here are the basic configuration settings:

```
Primary Router:
 - 192.168.1.1

Secondary Router (DD-WRT):
 - 192.168.2.1
 - Setup in client mode according to https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode_Wireless

Printer (Brother DCP-7065N)
 - Connected to Secondary Router
 - IP Address set to 192.168.2.110
```

I confirmed that the bridge was working.  When my laptop was connected via LAN-cable to the secondary router the internet connection was working so I know that it did connect to the primary router.

Now though I plugged in the printer to the secondary router and I don't know how to connect to it from a connection on the primary wifi network.  For example, on the command line `ping 192.168.2.110` just gives a timeout, and connecting through the Windows 10 printer dialog does give any acknowledgement of a printer at that address.  What am I missing here in order to connect to this printer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vince,

You need the second router in wireless bridge mode.
This is how you do it.

First of all, it will make this easier if you plug directly into the second router while configuring it.

### In the second routers configuration page go to the setup tab.

[image: dd-wrt setup]

1. Put the second router at the end of the first routers sub-net. example: 192.168.1.254 /24
2. Put it in DHCP forwarding mode and point it to the main router IP.
3. WAN & STP disabled.
4. Hit Save.

### In the Wireless tab --> Basic settings

[image: wireless setup tab]

1. Set the Wireless mode to Client Bridge.
2. Set the wireless network mode to what wireless mode you want it to connect to the first (choose the fastest mode both support).
3. Set your first routers SSID into the wireless network name box, or you can automatically populate it under Status -> Wireless.
4. Hit Save then go to the Wireless Security sub-tab and make sure your pre-shared key is correct.
5. Hit Save.

### In the Security Tab

1. Disable the SPI firewall.
2. Save & Apply.

[image: firewall]

Depending on model, you may have to reboot the router. Plugged in wired to the router, you should be able to go to Status -> Wireless and see that you are connected to the first routers wireless network.(with noise readings, RSSI etc). You should be given a DHCP IP address from inside the first routers Subnet.

That should be it. If you use client mode, this is synonymous with Firewall NAT-mode, and its not what you want when you are trying to bridge your network.

Hope this helps you out. Let me know if you run into trouble.

Comment: thanks again for the answer.  It worked beautifully.  I was a bit delayed in responding as we have had more snow than is morally right for April

Answer (score -1):

You probably have ddwrt in gateway mode. You should change in to Router mode, save and apply, also set a static route to 192.168.2.x via 192.168.1.(whatever WAN address of 2nd router is) on the primary router.

Then internal subnet will be visible from primary subnet.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the primary router is sadly an Apple Time Capsule and this https://superuser.com/questions/1071721/how-to-add-a-static-route-to-airport-time-capsule?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa seems to indicate I'm out of luck

Comment: This info is wrong, its generic and doesn't apply to DD-wrt modes. you don't want to ever try and bridge a network with NAT in the middle.

Comment: I think this is being mistaken with something else. Difference between "Gateway" and "Router" modes in ddwrt is the former does NAT traffic between LAN & WAN, while the latter is just a router, which we need for this question.